# Get total size of a list (containing HTTP links)

Tags: linux, files, wget, web

I have a file containing a list of files on the web, and I would like to know the total files' size (in human-readable format) and check their availability. Is there a command/solution to do so?

P.S. I know I should use `wget --spider` but I don't know how to use it with a list.

Comment: If you know you should use `wget`, what happens when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl to get the size of a file on the web without downloading it (provided the webserver supplies this information.) The technique is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497759/how-to-get-remote-file-size-from-a-shell-script).

Now, iterate over the list to get the size of each file:

```
cat files.lst | xargs -n 1 -I {} curl -sI {} | grep Content-Length | awk '{print $2}'
```

to get the list of sizes.

EDIT: You can of course use the awk to sum the sizes:

```
awk '{ sum+=$2 } END { print sum}'
```